# if (!string.equals.string) seems to be running all the time not only if it doesn't equal

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When running my code, I have come across ! before a statement to have negative or opposite of the statement. In this case if --- this string does not equal this string.

I've tried changing the second value in the string and it corrects it every time but I watch my tests and the values are correct and it still runs. I'm stuck wondering why because I need this as a check before moving on and Selenium 5-10% of the time types into the field too fast. This is why I implemented this check.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("inputcardNumberField")).sendKeys("41111111111111111");
WebElement visa = driver.findElement(By.id("inputcardNumberField"));

String visa2 = visa.getText();
    Thread.sleep(2000);

if (!visa2.equals("4111111111111111")) {                     
   driver.findElement(By.id("inputcardNumberField")).clear();    
   driver.findElement(By.id("inputcardNumberField")).sendKeys("4111111111111111"); 

   }
```

That if Selenium fills the inputcardNumberField too fast and the whole card # is not present.. it should clear and re-enter it.

If the correct card# is present it should not have to re-enter it. It re-enters it every time right now

Comment: You just called `sendKeys()` on the field. Why do you need to check if the keys you sent are in the field? This smells like you are testing that selenium behaves the way it advertises.

Comment: Did you try *debugging* your code, e.g. check the *actual* value of `visa2`? Then you'd see for yourself *why* it does what it does.

Comment: visa.getText() is going to return whatever's in between <input> and </input> it won't be the value of the text field itself.  To get the current value, you'll want to execute javascript.  If Selenium is typing too fast for this field to process, you might consider breaking apart the string into chars and looping with some sleeps in there.  I do this to more accurately simulate user typing: https://github.com/pcalkins/browsermator/blob/master/src/browsermator/com/TypeAtXPATHAction.java

Comment: @andreas I did.. it didn't print out anything.. So I'm not pulling a value - that makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like I was missing the get attribute value--  It should be like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("inputcardNumberField")).sendKeys("4111111111111111");
WebElement visa = driver.findElement(By.id("inputcardNumberField"));

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

String value = driver.findElement(By.id("inputcardNumberField")).getAttribute("value");         
    Thread.sleep(2000);

if (!visa2.equals("4111111111111111")) {
    driver.findElement(By.id("inputcardNumberField")).clear();           
    driver.findElement(By.id("inputcardNumberField")).sendKeys("4111111111111111"); 
    }
```